# p:selectOneMenu não filtra corretamente o dataList

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Tenho uma coluna com o filtro p:selectOneMenu . Uso para ele filtrar uma coluna que possui linhas que pode ter um ou vários atributos. Então uso o componente p:dataList do Primefaces para mostrar essa lista. Mas o filtro só pega o primeiro item do dataList, se filtrar pelos outros que estão na linha dessa coluna ele não filtra.

```
<p:column filterBy="#{projeto.listaLinhaPesquisas[0].nome}" headerText="Linha de Pesquisa">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('projetoTable').filter()" >
                    <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Selecione..." itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{gestaoProjetosBean.listaLinhaPesquisas}"
                        var="linhaPesquisa" itemLabel="#{linhaPesquisa.nome}"
                        itemValue="#{linhaPesquisa.nome}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
                <p:dataList value="#{projeto.listaLinhaPesquisas}" var="linhaPesquisa">
                    <h:outputText value="#{linhaPesquisa.nome}"/>
                </p:dataList>
            </p:column>
```

Comment: Você implementou o equals e hashcode?

Comment: Sim está implementado nas classes